# Can metadata of an object be changed in aws s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

While exploring S3 I came across metadata of an object.

The info icon there says "you can't modify them after they are set" but i am able to edit and delete values.

However I am not able to delete the value which I assigned during object creation but I am still able to edit it.

Is there any condition here on when can they be edited or deleted because its contradicting the statement provided in the info icon?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32646646/how-do-i-update-metadata-for-an-existing-amazon-s3-file

Comment: @Aky_0788 in the link you provided the marked anyswer says CANT , but i am able to edit and that is my doubt as mentioned above.